# IPhone application and IPad retina icon

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I've created an application for iPhone with icon versions for retina and no-retina display (icon@2x.png and icon.png).
Whenever I try to install this application on an iPad 3 a part of Default@2x.png is used instead of icon@2x.png. 
Have i to upload specific icon for iPad ? and in this case where!? from Xcode 4.3.2 I see only 2 spaces to include icons, but reserved for iPhone version. I suppose that i need to create a new voice into plist file... but I'm not sure and documentation didn't help me.

Comment: Clean and rebuild, sounds weird to me. The iPad 3 should use all retina imagery inside your app by default, including the default.png image of your first screen.... but you're saying it's using this in part of the icon? If it's iPhone only then of course you don't need to set any icons or anything at all for iPad users.

Comment: @Luke so i don't need to create a specific icon for iPad?

Comment: Well you just said it's an iPhone only app - naturally it will still run on an iPad; again as you said, in Xcode because your device target is set to iPhone rather than iPad or Universal then there is no option and no need to set iPad icons.

Comment: @MatterGoal Any luck with this? I have the same issue right now! If you can share your solution with me that would be awesome. Thanks mate.

Comment: @MatterGoal It would be nice to get a resolution for this question. I am having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Link to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11041153/377384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but with Xcode 6.3, if you use assets catalogs, select AppIcon, tick iPad (for iOS 7 and up) and add your 76x76 and 152x152 icons to the catalog

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem. I created the resource files Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png in the root of the bundle and added them to "Icon files" in the Info page of the target (Info.plist). Strangely, this didn't do the trick.

My final solution was to convert the target temporarily into an universal app, drag the iPad icons into the corresponding slots of the target's summary page and build it. After that, revert the target to an iPhone/iPod touch app, clean it, built it again.

Interestingly, this seems to work.

Comment: This worked for me too. To make it clear, I also had to delete the app from the simulator after switching back to an iPhone-only app (from Universal).

Comment: This works, because appropriate icon files (size) are added implicitly to the Info.plist. See my answer for the full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 more icons called

```
icon~ipad.png
icon@2x~ipad.png
```

The first one will allow for iPad 1/2, and the second one will allow for Retina iPads (iPad 3).

Adding those 2 icons may be enough. Also, try a Clean & Rebuild as Luke said.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: It didn't work for me. See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Icon-72. i used that

Answer (score 1):

When determining the appropriate App-Icon the OS searches the "best fitting size" Icon in the CFBundleIconFiles array or the CFBundleIcons in the Info.plist. If the Default(@2x).png is in one of those arrays, it is selected for best fitting on iPad Retina. Solutions:

1. Eliminate the Default(@2x).png from this arrays. For the Launch image there is another property. If you do that, the iPhone Retina Icon will be selected.
2. Optionally add the iPad resolution Icons (72, 72 / 144, 144) to one of those arrays. Then the OS will determine one of those as best fitting.

For the Info.plist keys see also:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

Consider, that the naming of those Icon files are only relevant for older iOS versions. In new versions, the OS just searches for sizes in the mentioned arrays.