# How do I specify an iPad Retina icon in XCode 4.3 for an iPhone-only app?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

My iPhone app icon shows up fine in iPhone/Retina and iPad. But on iPad retina (simulator and device) I get an icon that apparently contains the app's start screen:

[image]

Given that my app is designed for iPhone only (not 'Universal'), there is no option in Xcode 4.3 to add an iPad retina icon.

How can I get my app's icon to display correctly on iPad Retina devices?

Comment: I'll be the one to ask...why do you want your icon to display on iPad if the app doesn't run on iPad?

Comment: App runs on iPad in the same way that all iPhone apps run on iPad. The window is as large as an iPhone. You get a "2x" icon in the lower-right. Clicking it enlarges the app. AFAIK, this is nothing unusual. The real problem is the icon.

Comment: @IanHenry: [ADG](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) says so (see `2.10`).   The simulator has all kinds of problems related to icons and bundle resource refreshing BTW.  So long as this works on a regular device, it'll be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode the target summary interface where you add your icons and launch images is merely a graphical interface to the Info.plist file. When you make a iPhone only target, the graphical interface for the iPad portion is hidden. To add information to the Info.plist file that isn't covered by the graphical interface move to the Info tab and enter it there. To add the Retina iPad icons add an icon named Icon-72@2x.png and Icon-Small-50@2x.png to the Icon files array in the Info section. Also add actual 144 x 144 and 100 x 100 png representations of your icon with the proper name to your Xcode project and the target.

Comment: Adding an extra 144x144 pixel image to the 'Icon files (iOS 5)-> 'Icon files' Info.plist array followed by dragging the file itself onto the top-level project tab in Xcode (to add the file to the project) did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem with an app too, and when I went to edit the Info.plist file found that Default@2x.png was in the icon list - no idea how it got there, but this project has been going on a while so could be a result of one too many XCode upgrades.

Removing it from the entries in the plist has fixed the problem on the retina iPad too. Am still going to add the extra iPad icons in just in case, but if others are having the problem it is worth checking what XCode has put in those entries.